# Angular 2+Nativescript

Tags: angular, nativescript

'Im new to the angular 2 and nativescript. I would like to create a social network platform application that can run on web and on mobile. but there is no tutorials or documentation. So, if anyone could give me some directions for start, how can I do this.

Thanks!

Comment: while you can use nativescript as a platform for angular, it does not mean that you can use the same application for browser and for mobile app (using nativescript). If you want to build an application that will be (mostly) the same on browser and on mobile, you should take a look at hybrid solutions like cordova or ionic 2.

Comment: It is confusing because NativeScript is not a programming language it is a platform. Angular 2, on the other hand is also not a language but it wants to be and it's slowly forking TypeScript

Answer (score 0):

Check **Ionic 2 framework**, you can create mobile apps using **Angular 2** technology, I strongly recommend it because I have built apps very fast and it's very *well documented*, it has a problem which it's that *some plugins* to interact with hardware aren't so easy to handle.

**Nativescript** it's an open source project which integrates **Angular 2 and Javascript**, it has a better *performance* interacting with android hardware but it's *harder* to learn and it's probably that the current version will *change* soon.

Comment: You should explain how they are different. I don't think the OP is clear on that.

Comment: @Aluan that's correct maybe if I know the difference then I can be able to choose either ionic or nativescript

Comment: @DaveDev I have forgotten to explain more why in my opinion, I choose Ionic 2.